# How to Solve System of Equations When Some Variables Are Already Chosen?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, scipy-optimize

I'm using `scipy.optimize` to minimize a cost function.

Python passes M variables into the cost function, and N other variables are calculated based on those. Now, I have a system of M+N simultaneous equations which must be satisfied for a solution to be valid.

I imagine doing something like this:

```python
def cost(someTuple):
    # This function calculates the cost
    return k1 * someTuple[0] + k2 * someTuple[1] + ... kN * someTuple[N-1]

def cost_wrapper(x):
    # ************ The following line is what I don't know how to do *************
    big_tuple = solveSystemOfEquations(x, f(x))
    return cost(big_tuple)

if __name__=="__main__":
    from scipy.optimize import minimize
    minimize(cost_wrapper, *otherParams)
```

What is important about `solveSystemOfEquations()` is that it returns more variables than are given to it. If the variables given to it are far removed from any possible solution, `solveSystemOfEquations()` has to return a large number with a gradient that will lead the optimizer towards a meaningful solution.

Let's also assume that the system is approximately solvable. Note that boundedness of MMSE error of a solution cannot be guaranteed.

Is there any algorithm which allows you to choose some (not all) variables, and solve for the others? Or is that not a thing?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to fix the values of some variables being passed to `solveSystemOfEquations()` and minimize other variables? Or did I misunderstand you completely?

Comment: I solve a lot of optimization problems, but I never solve a system of equations inside a model. I just add to the model constraints `Ax=b` or `F(x)=b`. (I use LP/NLP solvers that allow many constraints).

Comment: @MuhammadMohsinKhan I want to fix the values of some variables and calculate what other variables must be in order to satisfy a system of equations.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I realize this is an unusual thing to do, which is why I'm reaching out for help. Can you give me an example the sort of constraints you can enter into these LP/NLP solvers? What library are they a part of?

Comment: A general NLP solver typically wants smooth functions in the constraints (i.e. continuous and differentiable).